# What is the equation relating Vin and Vout on a 2-Port Network?

Tags: circuit-analysis, circuit-design, passive-networks, wireless-charging, transimpedance

I was reviewing a [paper](https://chrismi.sdsu.edu/publications/2015_Wei_Zhang_TVT2454292_Compensation_topology.pdf), and I got stuck while trying to understand the analysis of the two-port network.

This is the circuit below with the equation below it
[image: Resonant Network with T-configuration]
[image: Vin and Vout is related by]

This is my attempt below, my knowledge of circuit analysis is not very rigorous, so I am using circuit dividers to try to prove it. Please what did I miss out, and are there other ways (or simpler methods) of proving this...?

[image]

**Please any help would be appreciated!**

Comment: In your first equation (1), you didn't take into account the loading effect of Z2 and RL. Replace Z3 in that equation by Z3||(Z2+RL).

Comment: [This might help you solve it yourself](http://www.stades.co.uk/Impedance%20TX/Zmatch%20basic.html)

Comment: Please, better late than never...
Thank you @LetterSized for the clarification. I saw I actually made similar errors in related problems, so I had to retrace and correct. Thank you

Comment: Thanks @Andyaka, your page kept me busy for some days...:)! 
however, It seems the content is deeper than my current knowledge level... 
I hope to grasp it well someday. 
Please my humble apologies for the late response